# Sorting High to Low value in the array

Tags: php, arrays

need value advice and help me to sort out the following issue.

```
function max_key($array) {
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    if ($val == max($array)) return $key;
    }
}

$SortingVote = array();

for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {

   $SortingVote[] = $i;
}

$array = $SortingVote;

$array_count=count($array);    
for($i=0;$i<=$array_count;$i++){
    $max_val[$i]=max_key($array);

    $voteValue_View=$array[$max_val[$i]];

    unset($array[$max_val[$i]]);


    $VoteValue_New[$i] = $voteValue_View;
    echo "Vote Value manual = $VoteValue_New[$i] <br />"; 
}
```

It works fine and display the value when I am running it on my local machine via MAMP Mac version (PhP & MySQL). But, it display nothing when I deployed on my production server. And it is weird? Just received the following:

```
Vote Value manual =
```

Appreciate if anyone can guide me on this. Cheers

Comment: You will need to provide more information as to what you are trying to achieve, including example of input.

Comment: whats that code supposed to do? are you aware that there is various native functions for sorting?

Comment: Have you checked the server log? Something like `tail /var/log/apache2/error.log` in ubuntu or `tail /var/log/httpd/error_log` in centos/RHEL
`

Comment: Wondering if there is any simple solution to sort the max to low value in the array variable? Just could not get the above sort out. Hope to find something simple.

Comment: first result on google for array sorting in php: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just rewriting this, seems easier:

```
arsort($array);
foreach(array_slice($array,0,10,true) as $key => $value){
     echo "Vote Value manual = $value <br />"; 
}
```

Comment: Wondering if there is any simple solution to sort the max to low value in the array variable? Just could not get the above sort out. Hope to find something simple.

Comment: Thats the `arsort`, sorts the array high-to-low, maintaining index association (if you don't need the latter, just use `rsort`).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and got it sorted finally. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Not to immediately address your issue, but you clearly have a misconfiguration between your production and your development server. Most likely this is in `php.ini`. Do you have access to the `php.ini` on production? If so, check whether it has:

```
log_errors = On
```

If it does, it will be logging errors to a log file (though not displaying them, since it is a production server). In this case, you should be able to look into the error log to see what is upsetting it.

Comment: Wondering if there is any simple solution to sort the max to low value in the array variable? Just could not get the above sort out. Hope to find something simple.